# How to use org.apache.httpcomponents inside a spark job on Hadoop/Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, gradle

I am trying to run a spark job on a Hadoop cluster that also makes an http request to another server. I am using org.apache.httpcomponents to make this request, which works fine locally on my machine. However this fails the moment I submit the job to the cluster (managed by Cloudera) with the following error:

> User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
>   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:977)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:56)

From all the reading I have done, this error is caused by multiple versions of Apache Http client jar. It appears that Hadoop/Spark engine has it's own dependency to Apache Http client and that is a different version than the one I am using. Because my jar is run as part of the hadoop/spark engine it ends up including both my version of http as well as the one Hadoop requires.

If I add 'compileOnly' for org.apache.httpcomponents in my build.gradle and submit, I get this error instead:

> User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients

Is there a way for me to configure this in gradle so that when I build my jar, it will use the already existing version on Hadoop? ie. A way to declare a temporary dependency (when running locally download and use latest version, but when building UberJar drop the dependency)?

**UPDATE**
I decided to try swapping to a different http library (okhttp3) to see if that would resolve the issue. However I get a very similar exception when trying to run through the cluster here too:

> User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
>   at okhttp3.internal.Util.(Util.kt:70)
>   at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.(OkHttpClient.kt:959)

Looks like Cloudera also supplies a version of okhttp with it's spark2 client which is unfortunate.

Comment: Hey, did you happen to check out this link from CLDR community? https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-provide-a-different-dependency-for-RDD-in-spark/td-p/189387

Comment: @gsthina Thanks for the link, it looks like shaded jar is the only way to do this currently. Will give it a shot and report back.

Comment: did you have a chance to cehck it out?